# How to (best) play a sound repeatedly in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mediaelement

I need to play a sound repeatedly every X milliseconds. Is it best to use the XNA framework or MediaElement? (I'm not using XNA for anything else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can the soundfiles overlap each other? If yes go and use XNA because you can only have one MediaElement per page.
For getting started see [dotnetscraps](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Play-multiple-sound-files-in-Silverlight-for-Windows-Phone-7.aspx).

Comment: Thanks,  XNA is the way to go.